# how to implement hash function `h(k) = (A·k mod 2^w) >> (w – r)` in Java

Tags: java, hash-function

IMPORTANT NOTICE:

This is not a discussion thread for people to give me their opinion about hashing. I just need to know how to make the given function work in java -- an example would be best.

PROBLEM:

Trying to hone my understanding of hash functions for a pending interview, I watch two free lectures by MIT computer science professors (http://videolectures.net/mit6046jf05_leiserson_lec08/). So after the lecture, I am trying to implement the following hash function in java.

```
h(k) = (A·k mod 2^w) >> (w – r)
WHERE
r: m, the size of the array, is a power of 2 such that m=2^r
w: the computer has w-bit words, such as 32-bit or 64-bit computer
k: the value I am to find a key for
A: a random odd number (prime would be great) between 2^(w-1) and 2^w
```

I thought this would be easy to implement in java. But when I do 2^w where w=32, I get inaccurate results in Java. In real life `2^32 = 4294967296` but not in java, which truncates the result to `2^31 - 1` or `2147483647`.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem so to implement the function in Java?

EDIT:

I see a lot of the replies focus on 32. What if my computer is 64 bit? I am stuck with setting `w = 32` because I am using Java?

Comment: how about using w=31 instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the terms are redundant because Java assumes this behaviour anyway.

```
A·k mod 2^w
```

In Java, integer multiplication overflows and thus does a mod `2^w` (with a sign). The fact that it has a sign doesn't matter if you are then shifting by at least one bit.

Shift of `(w - r)` is the same as a shift of `-r` in Java (the w is implied by the type)

```
private static final int K_PRIME = (int) 2999999929L;

public static int hash(int a, int r) {
   // return (a * K_PRIME % (2^32)) >>> (32 - r);
   return (a * K_PRIME) >>> -r;
}
```

for 64-bit

```
private static final long K_PRIME = new BigInteger("9876534021204356789").longValue();

public static long hash(long a, int r) {
    // return (a * K_PRIME % (2^64)) >>> (64 - r);
    return (a * K_PRIME) >>> -r;
}
```

---

I have written this example to show you can do the same thing in BigInteger and why you wouldn't. ;)

```
public static final BigInteger BI_K_PRIME = new BigInteger("9876534021204356789");
private static long K_PRIME = BI_K_PRIME.longValue();

public static long hash(long a, int r) {
    // return (a * K_PRIME % (2^64)) >>> (64 - r);
    return (a * K_PRIME) >>> -r;
}

public static long biHash(long a, int r) {
    return BigInteger.valueOf(a).multiply(BI_K_PRIME).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(64)).shiftRight(64 - r).longValue();
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        long a = rand.nextLong();
        for (int r = 1; r < 64; r++) {
            long h1 = hash(a, r);
            long h2 = biHash(a, r);
            if (h1 != h2)
                throw new AssertionError("Expected " + h2 + " but got " + h1);
        }
    }

    int runs = 1000000;
    long start1 = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
        hash(i, i & 63);
    long time1 = System.nanoTime() - start1;

    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
        biHash(i, i & 63);
    long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
    System.out.printf("hash with long took an average of %,d ns, " +
            "hash with BigInteger took an average of %,d ns%n",
            time1 / runs, time2 / runs);
}
```

prints

```
hash with long took an average of 3 ns, \
    hash with BigInteger took an average of 905 ns
```

Comment: What if I am using a 64 bit computer? The hash function specifies `w` as the word size of the computer being used. Any thoughts?

Comment: Whether you have a 32-bit JVM on 32-bit machine, a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit machine or 64-bit JVM doesn't matter in Java as you will always get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `int` nor `long` would be sufficiently large enough to hold all of the values you'd need in 2^(w-1).  You would be best served with [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: I will give this a try to see how it goes.

Comment: You don't need BigInteger is all you are going to do is `% 2^w` the result.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look what `number % 2^32` actually does: It gets the remainder of the division by 2^32. If you have a range from 0 to 2^32, the computer will automatically do the modulo for you, because it throws away everything above 2^32.

Let's take 8 instead of 32, and switch to binary number system:

```
  1000 1000 % 1 0000 0000 = 1000 1000
1 1000 1000 % 1 0000 0000 = 1000 1000
```

So what you should do is to limit the number to the range of the computer. If you would use e.g. c++, it would be as simple as declaring the value as `unsigned int`. The first `1` of the second example above would simply be truncated because it does not fit into the variable.

In java, you don't have unsigned integers. If you calculate `A * k`, and that results in an overflow, you may get a signed value. But as the only thing you have to do next is to do a right shift, this should not matter.

So my suggestion is to simply drop the modulo calculation. Try it, I'm not quite sure whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

The Java primative `int` has a range of minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647

Check out this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for details on the primatives.

I recommend using a `long` instead of an `int`.

Comment: I did try `long`. No difference.